# Написание программы с ветвлением в C++

Tags: c++, c

Есть условие задачи: **Напиши программу, которая спрашивает “Уроки сделаны?”, если пользователь отвечает “y”- программа выводит на экран “Молодец!”. Во всех остальных случаях ничего не выводит.**
Я написал следующие код, но застрял на том, как сравнить переменную и букву "y"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Уроки сделаны?");
  char a;
  scanf("%c", &a);
  if (a == "y") 
  {
      printf("Молодец!");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'y'` вместо `"y"`.

Comment: @tocic спасибо, все работает, а можете объяснить в чем разница в данному случаи?

Comment: Разница в том, что `'y'` - символ, а `"y"` - строка.  Это объясняется в начале практически любого учебника по C/C++

Comment: Если очень хочется сравнивать со строкой, то `if (a == "y"[0])` сравнивает с первым символом строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть:

if ( a == 'y')

Как-то так